# Find intersection measure of a probability space

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I have that $(X,\mathbf{A},\mu)$ is a probability space and $A,B \in \mathbf{A}$ with $\mu(A)=\frac{5}{12}$ , $\mu(B)=\frac{1}{2}$ and $\mu((A\cup B)^{c}) = \frac{1}{4}$.

I would like to find $\mu(A\cap B )$.

Is it correct to calculate that $\mu(A\cup B) = 1 - \mu((A\cup B)^{c}) = 1 - \frac{1}{4} = \frac{3}{4}$?

And then use the fact that $\mu(A\cup B) + \mu(A\cap B) = \mu(A) + \mu(B)$ to find that
$\mu(A\cap B) = \mu(A) + \mu(B) - \mu(A\cup B) = \frac{5}{12} + \frac{1}{2} - \frac{3}{4} = \frac{1}{6}$ ?

I'm not sure about this so any input would be much appreciated!

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your input.